# How to proof that $\arcsin(3x+3)$ is injective

Tags: functions

I'm trying to prove that $\arcsin(3x+3)$ function is injective. I know that it passes vertical test.
But I just don't know how to prove it.
[image: graph of an arcsin function]

Comment: Prove that it is strictly increasing.

Comment: The composition $f \circ g$ of two injective functions $f(u) = \arcsin(u)$ and $g(x) = 3x + 3$ is injective.

Comment: Well.... Suppose $\arcsin(3x+3)=\arcsin(3y+3)$. Then $\sin (\arcsin(3x+3)) =\sin(\arcsin(3y+3))$ and $3x+3 = 3y+3$ and $x=y$.  ... Now that might seem a little glib and you might se that $\sin$ is not injective.  But that's okay as we are not claiming the *input* are equal  (claiming $\sin x = \sin y \implies x =y$ would be WRONG), we are claiming the *output* are equal (claiming $x = y \implies \sin x = \sin y$ is RIGHT).

Comment: The derivative of your function is positive. Using the mean value theorem, we can prove that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$, and $f'$ is positive on $(a,b)$, then $f$ is strictly increasing (and hence injective).